# Java Threading behavior

Tags: java

I saw the following example on the internet:

```
public class TwoThreads {
public static class Thread1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("A");
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
public static class Thread2 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread1().start();
    new Thread2().start();
}
```

}

My question is :

1. It is guarantee that "A" will be printed Before "B" and "1" will be printed before "2", but is it possible that "1" will be printed twice successively by another thread?.In this piece of code we have at least 3 threads(1 main and 2 created). can we imagine the scheduler runs 1 thread: new Thread1().start(); then gave up immediately after System.out.println("1"); then again run another threat in Thread1().start(); that prints "1" again ?
2. I am using NetBeans IDE, it seems running such a program always lead to the same first result, so it seems there something with caching. From my understanding you deal with that with declaring volatile variables, can it be done here,how ? if not then what is the solution for caching ?
3. In today's Computer's processor, we mostly have 2 processors,and still we find many multi-threading programs on the net uses more than 2 threads! isn't this process becomes heavy and slow regarding compiling ?

Comment: I never understand these questions. If you want a specific order, why are you using threads at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your 1/2 question:
Though threads run parallel code inside run method of thread is always executed sequentially.

Answer to your 3 question you can best tune your. Application if number of processors = number of threads but this is not a complete truth since if thread is waiting for some blocking operation then it will lead to un optimized performance since during that time another thread could run.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no guarantee in what order the threads will proceed.

2) The order is not randomized, either, though. So if you run the program under identical (or very similar) conditions, it will probably yield the same thread interleaving. If you need to have a certain behaviour (including randomized behaviour) you need to synchronized things yourself.

3) A CPU with two cores can only run two threads at the same time, but most threads spend most of their time not actually using the CPU, but waiting for something like I/O or user interaction. So you can gain a lot from having more than two threads (only two can concurrently compute, but hundreds can concurrently wait).  Take a look at node.js, a recently popular alternative to multi-threaded programming that achieves great throughput for concurrent requests while having only a single thread of execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. No.  You are not synchronizing your threads in any way, so the exact execution order will be at the mercy of the scheduler.  Given how your threads are implemented, I don't see how you could ever having "1" (or "A") being printed twice by a single thread.
2. What caching?  And what variables?  Your example code has no variables, and therefore nothing that would be appropriate to use with the `volatile` keyword.  It's quite likely that on a given machine running this program will always produce the same result.  As noted in #1, you're at the mercy of the scheduler.  If the scheduler always behaves the same way, you'll always get the same result.  Caching has nothing to do with it.
3. That depends upon what the threads are doing.  If every thread has enough work to load one CPU core to 100%, then yes, having more threads than you have CPU cores is pointless.  However, this is very rarely the case.  Many threads will spend most of their time sleeping, or waiting for I/O to complete, or otherwise doing things that are not demanding enough to fully load a CPU core.  In such a case there's no problem whatsoever with having more threads that CPU cores.  In fact, multithreading predates mainstream multicore CPU's, and even back in the days when none of us had more than one CPU core it was still extremely beneficial to be able to have more than one thread.

Comment: Hi aroth .<br> In question 1) because my program has no synchronization,In this piece of code we have at least 3 threads(1 main and 2 created). can we imagine the scheduler runs 1 thread: new Thread1().start(); then gave up immediately after System.out.println("1"); then again run another threat in the same way ?